# How to exclude nested model in Ecto Poison encoding

Tags: elixir, ecto, elixir-poison

I have a simple model (short version) :

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use Ecto.Model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :name, :email]}
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    belongs_to :company, MyApp.Company
```

I expect the `@derive` to exclude `:company` associations while trying to encode the model, but it doesn't seem to. This happens while using Guardian serializer :

```
defmodule MyApp.GuardianSerializer do
  @behaviour Guardian.Serializer

  alias MyApp.Repo
  alias MyApp.User

  def for_token(user = %User{}), do: { :ok, "User:#{user.id}" }
  def for_token(_), do: { :error, "Unknown resource type" }

  def from_token("User:" <> id), do: { :ok, Repo.get(User, id) }
  def from_token(_), do: { :error, "Unknown resource type" }
end
```

I'm not actually sure to understand what happens with

`def for_token(user = %User{}), do: { :ok, "User:#{user.id}" }`

From what i understand `user =  %User{}` is trying to test if the object given as a parameter is a valid `User` changeset right ?

But i get this error instead :

> cannot encode association :company from MyApp.User to JSON because the
>   association was not loaded. Please make sure you have preloaded the
>   association or remove it from the data to be encoded

I do not want to preload it, because it will require more dependencies to encode which doesn't work either, i would prefer to ignore it.

Why the `only` param in `@derive` doesn't work and how could I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do `Poison.encode!(Repo.get(User, 1))` (replacing 1 with a valid user id)?

Comment: I have updated the question and added some context. Yes the same problem occurs if i try to encode it directly with `Poison.encode!/1`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a similar setup: `Comment` belongs_to `Post`; `Poison.encode!(Repo.get(Comment, 1))` with `@derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :content]}` on `Comment`. Can you try to reproduce the error in a new minimal app?

Comment: Are you preloading the association ? If I preload it, the error continues with associations of `Company` which are not preloaded... but i don't want to preload or encode any of these.

Comment: Yes, even this works fine: `Poison.encode! MyApp.Repo.get(MyApp.Comment, 2) |> MyApp.Repo.preload([:post])` with the same `@derive` as I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it requires to load the associations even with `@derive` set. I don't know what's wrong and why you don't have any issue

Comment: I'm testing on `poison` 2.2.0, `ecto` 2.0.2 and `phoenix` 1.2.0.

Comment: @Sylver any updates? I've checked with model which uses guardian and it works for me too. May be something which we aren't see in your example?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

I had a fix in my project related to an older version of Ecto, you can find a discussion about that [here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/840), and the suggestion for the fix i used [here](https://coderwall.com/p/fhsehq/fix-encoding-issue-with-ecto-and-poison)

So, basically i was already redefining the `Poison.Encoder` elsewhere, for everything (I know, this is pretty bad to have done that, and as usual, it was something meant to be temporary...)

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Any do
  def encode(%{__struct__: _} = struct, options) do
    map = struct
          |> Map.from_struct
          |> sanitize_map
    Poison.Encoder.Map.encode(map, options)
  end

  defp sanitize_map(map) do
    Map.drop(map, [:__meta__, :__struct__])
  end
end
```

By removing it, with the last version of `ecto`/`poison`/`phoenix`/you-name-it, it works as expected.

Thanks a lot for your help @dogbert